# Is there an alternative to finding the characteristic equation of a square matrix

Tags: matrices

Given a square matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda$, we have the formulas $\det{A}=\prod{\lambda_i}$ and $\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{tr} \Tr(A)=\sum{\lambda_i}$ , so is there (simple) formulas for the other sum of products i.e. $\sum{\lambda_1\lambda_2}$ ,  $\sum{\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3}$ . This would be an easier way to obtain the characteristic equation rather than expanding $|A-{\lambda}I|$

Comment: The other sums of products are called the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). I don't personally know of any closed forms for elementary symmetric polynomials applied to the eigenvalues of a matrix, but I know that people have thought about it. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120365/655547) for instance. The machinery in the accepted answer might be higher brow than you're looking for, but maybe something in Andrius Kulikauskas's PhD thesis will be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Let the characteristic polynomial be $f(\lambda)$.

$f(\lambda)=\lambda^n+a_1\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n$

We can prove that $a_r=(-1)^r\sum\limits_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\le n}A$
$
\begin{gathered}
\begin{pmatrix} 
i_1 & i_2 & \cdots & i_r \\ 
i_1 & i_2 & \cdots & i_r\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\end{gathered}
$
$r=1,2,\cdots,n.$

Also,we can denote this equation as

$\sum\limits_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\le n}\lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}\cdots\lambda_{i_r}$
$=(-1)^r\sum\limits_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\le n}A$
$\begin{gathered}
\begin{pmatrix} 
i_1 & i_2 & \cdots & i_r \\ 
i_1 & i_2 & \cdots & i_r\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\end{gathered}$
$ r=1,2,\cdots,n.$

Comment: @Newb , the proof can be done with Laplace Theorem.$|A+B|=\sum\nolimits M\tilde{M}$

Comment: $M$ denotes any submatrix of $A$, when $\tilde{M}$ denotes the algebraic cofactor of the corresponding submatrix of $B$.